# Android - redraw canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I have **3** ImageViews. **1st** and **2nd** **connected** with red **line**. Also I have simple button. Here is a picture:

[image]

I want to **connect** **2nd & 3rd** ImageViews with **new Path line** and **change the first line color** (for example to Green) when i clicking my button. Here is parts of my code:

```
public class SkillPath extends View {
Paint paint;
Path path;

... constructors


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    addPath (canvas);       
}

//Here is my RED line
void addPath (Canvas canvas){
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(3);

    path.moveTo(110, 110);
    path.lineTo(210, 110);

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    Log.d ("Page 2","onDraw");
}
```

I can get all coordinates of all Views, but **how can I redraw existing canvas**? I suspect, I need to use **invalidate()**, but I do not know enough to do this. Need help.

Answer (score 2):

The `invalidate()` method forces the `View` to be re-drawn.

So just apply the modification you need on your canvas and call `invalidate()` on the related `View` after these modifications.